# WPF event for clicking textboxes in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I raise an event while clicking a textbox? I'm having trouble finding references for events for WPF in C#.

The idea is to have textboxes fire an event when clicked. For example, let's say as soon as I click a textbox, notepad is executed.

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     hello = Process.Start("notepad");   
 }
 private void Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
 {    
     /* if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
     {
         hello = Process.Start(@"notepad");                
     }*/           
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For text events use TextInput event and read entered character from e.Text

```
private void yourTextBox_TextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{  
    if (e.Text == "K")
    {
    }
}
```

for mouse events use MouseDown/MouseUp

Sometimes MouseDown/MouseUp won't work on TextBox, then use this one:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmouseup.aspx

Answer (score 0):

MouseLeftButtonDown event can be raised when clicking on textbox. This event will not fire by default on   textbox. We need to use UIElement.AddHandler().

For e.g:

#### XAML:

```
<Textbox X:Name="Name_Textbox" MouseLeftButtonDown="Name_Textbox_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
```

#### In the class Constructor:

```
TextBox_Name.AddHandler(FrameworkElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler("Name_Textbox_MouseLeftButtonDown"), true);
```

#### Add Event in class file:

```
private void Name_Textbox_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)  
{
   // Your logic on textbox click
}
```